# How can I set certain text to be read into a textfield in GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, inputstream

I'm working on an assignment using Binary IO and Event Handling. It looks like this, I think I have most of the basic code down, and now its down to the hard stuff.  How can I read text from my .bin file into the seperate text fields? 
[image]

My fields currently are blank, but when read in they should look something like that and I should be able to parse through seperate sets of information with my two buttons on the bottom.

Here is what I have so far.
I have a RecordViewerUI JFrame form, a RecordViewerPanel JFrame panel, and a SalesAgent java class which holds all of my getters and setters/ constructor for my four variables.

Here is my panel. Sorry for the generated code.
Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class RecordViewerPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

String filename = "sales.bin";
ArrayList<SalesAgent> customer = new ArrayList<>();
int curIndex = 0;

/**
 * Creates new form RecordViewerPanel
 */
public RecordViewerPanel() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    initComponents();
    try {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(filename)));
        ArrayList<SalesAgent> salesForce = new ArrayList<SalesAgent>();
        String first = in.readUTF();
        String last = in.readUTF();
        double sales = in.readDouble();
        Date date = (Date) (in.readObject());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RecordViewerPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

private void refreshUI() {
    SalesAgent sale = (customer.get(curIndex));
    firstTextField.setText(sale.getFirst());
    lastTextField.setText(sale.getLast());
    salesTextField.setText("$" + String.valueOf(sale.getSales()));
    dateTextField.setText(String.valueOf(sale.getDate()));
    recordPanel.repaint();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    filePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    fileLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    fileLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    recordPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    firstTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    lastTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    salesTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    dateTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    previousButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    nextButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

    filePanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

    fileLabel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
    fileLabel.setText("sales.bin");

    fileLabel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
    fileLabel1.setText("Current file:");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout filePanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(filePanel);
    filePanel.setLayout(filePanelLayout);
    filePanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        filePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(filePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(94, 94, 94)
            .addComponent(fileLabel)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(filePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(filePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(fileLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(562, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
    );
    filePanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        filePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(filePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(fileLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
        .addGroup(filePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(filePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(fileLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap()))
    );

    recordPanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

    firstTextField.setText("jTextField1");

    lastTextField.setText("jTextField1");

    salesTextField.setText("jTextField1");

    dateTextField.setText("jTextField1");

    jLabel1.setText("First                             Last                             Sales                            Date");

    previousButton.setText("<<");
    previousButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            previousButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    nextButton.setText(">>");
    nextButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            nextButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout recordPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(recordPanel);
    recordPanel.setLayout(recordPanelLayout);
    recordPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        recordPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(recordPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(recordPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(recordPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 415, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 203, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(recordPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(firstTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(lastTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(salesTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(dateTextField)))
            .addContainerGap())
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, recordPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(previousButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 53, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(nextButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 53, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(31, 31, 31))
    );
    recordPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        recordPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(recordPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(29, 29, 29)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(recordPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(firstTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(lastTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(salesTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(dateTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 35, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(recordPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(previousButton)
                .addComponent(nextButton))
            .addGap(27, 27, 27))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(filePanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addComponent(recordPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(filePanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(recordPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void previousButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    if (curIndex > 0) {
        curIndex--;
    } else if (curIndex == 0) {
        curIndex = 4;
    }
    customer.get(curIndex);
}                                              

private void nextButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    if (curIndex < 4) {
        curIndex++;
    } else if (curIndex == 4) {
        curIndex = 0;
    }
    customer.get(curIndex);
}                                          
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField dateTextField;
private javax.swing.JLabel fileLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel fileLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel filePanel;
private javax.swing.JTextField firstTextField;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField lastTextField;
private javax.swing.JButton nextButton;
private javax.swing.JButton previousButton;
private javax.swing.JPanel recordPanel;
private javax.swing.JTextField salesTextField;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: To start with `customer` and `salesForce` seem to the same thing, but your are declearing `salesForce` locally to the constructor, which will mean it won't be usable beyond it.  You seem to reading content from the file, but you're not doing anything with it...

Comment: But, if I get rid of customer, which I should, then my get(curIndex) in the top of my refreshUI() method would be out of scope wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes I'm reading it, but how can I assign it to the different values of text fields, there are 5 sets of information in the file, how can I assign the first name to firstTextField, the last name to lastTextField, the sales to salesTextfield, and so on?

Comment: But you've already done this (kind of thing) in the `refreshUI` method...I would assume you need to get the values into a `SalesAgent` object and added to the appropriate list...

Comment: Yes I do, how would I go about doing that since I'm reading it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather difficult to answer, as I have no understanding of the file format or the `Customer` class, but basically, you need to create a new `Customer` from the values you've read from the file, add it to the `customer` `List` and call `refreshUI`

```
try {
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(filename)));
    String first = in.readUTF();
    String last = in.readUTF();
    double sales = in.readDouble();
    Date date = (Date) (in.readObject());
    Customer cust = ...;
    customer.add(cust);
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(RecordViewerPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
refreshUI();
```